# chkconfig on for arbitrary path program

Tags: linux, centos, boot, chkconfig

Noramlly to add a start up program one have something like

```
 chkconfig httpd on
```

however how can I do this for a program that I need to start like

```
/usr/local/program/sbin/program
```

? I tried

```
chkconfig /usr/local/program/sbin/program on
```

but it said

error reading information on service /usr/local/program/sbin/program: No such file or directory

Unfortunately all the example I found online is chkconfig [service name] on.

Answer (score 3):

Read the `chkconfig` man page, specifically the `--add` section and the `RUNLEVEL FILES` section.

Answer (score 3):

- Add to your script these example lines:

`#chkconfig: 345 80 20` 
`#description: example script`

**Explanation:** 
345 - levels 
80 - start priority 
20 - stop priority

Of course, these are example values, you can change it.

- Add your script with command:

`chkconfig --add`

Answer (score 1):

chkconfig manage the links under /etc/rcX.d/ for the scripts in the directory /etc/init.d